# High Charts export image on the server

Tags: php, highcharts

I am exporting image on the server using High chart.Using the below code

```
exporting: { url:'example.com/highcharts/exporting-server/php/php-batik/' }
```

I have download `batik-rasterizer-1.6.jar` and extract the zip file and rename the folder to batik-  rasterizer.jar and put the folder in the following route.

```
example.com/highcharts/exporting-server/php/php-batik/batik-rasterizer.jar
```

and index.php file i used below code

```
define ('BATIK_PATH', 'batik-rasterizer.jar');
```

When I converting, I got the following error:

```
Error while converting SVG.
```

Comment: Looks like you're using the java option highcharts has provided - Have you referred to their docs when you installed it and tested it with their test script? http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server Don't forget to turn on logging, so you get more information about what the issue is.

Comment: I am using 1. Export server based on PHP and Batik
Please guide me about batik-rasterizer.jar  
How can I install

Comment: All the instructions are on the link I provided.

Comment: Please guide me point # 5

Upload batik-rasterizer.jar and the entire lib directory to a location on your web server.

Comment: I uploaded batik-rasterizer.jar but what is entire lib?

Comment: That's a directory from the files you got.

Comment: In the zip file downloaded from Batik you'll find the Batik-Rasterizer.jar file and a folder named 'lib'. Both file and folder should be copied to the server. A common place to copy to, is  alongside the index.php

Comment: In the zip file downloaded from Batik.When I expanded it. I found Batik-Rasterizer.jar zip folder not file inside Batikfolder.I also found lib folder.But I dont know where is Batik-Rasterizer.jar file.I placed the Batik-Rasterizer.jar zip folder and lib folder in same directory where index.php file exist

Answer (score 4):

If for any reason the export-server fails to export images, then consider pasting this code snippet to output error messages. Paste this before Line 78, beginning with the commenting text:

**Paste before**

```
// Do the conversion.
```

**This snippet**

```
// Troubleshoot snippet
$command = "java -jar ". BATIK_PATH ." $typeString -d $outfile $width temp/$tempName.svg 2>&1"; 
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo "Command: $command <br>";
echo "Output: $output";
die;
```

This will hopefully reveal the underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks... I did this and found that I just had to add my java location to the system Path variable.